# How to fight brutes and officers in Assassin's Creed: Unity?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

Could you give tips and tricks on how to fight brutes and officers in Assassin's Creed: Unity? I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your skill set a bit. But I can provide you with some basic tips on how to fight them.

So as you probably know (for you to be asking) these are the hardest types of enemies. You can't perfect parry them and they are stronger than regular enemies.

> - If you can't Perfect Parry them, just **DODGE** (<kbd>**X**</kbd>(**PS4**)).
>
> Dodge is one move I personally practice a lot. It always helps in these difficult situations because the Parry won't counter their attacks. So Dodge and Strike.

You can still Parry them but just remember it won't be a Perfect Parry so they aren't gonna be affected much.

> - If you're stuck in a fight with these guys and you see yourself about to die, remember the **Smoke Bombs** (<kbd>**R1**</kbd>(**PS4**)) .
>
> They are absolutely over-powered in combat. So if you want to use them go ahead because they won't even have the chance to parry your attacks.

Depending on your skill set you can use stun bombs on them to stun them a bit (Required Stun Bomb skill). The combat push where you hold <kbd>**X**</kbd> on the **PS4** and Arno shuvs an enemy to the ground. If you have these skills you can use them to help in difficult fights.

As a final piece of advice, stay out of combat if you're fighting more than 3/4 guys. And if you see the icon above your head that one of them is about to shoot you just try to **dodge** the shot. It's the only way